# How to decide order of processing of the thread components GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I've this code:

```
final DialogBox menuWrapper = new DialogBox(true);
MenuBar options = new MenuBar(true);
menuWrapper.add(options);
options.addItem("First", new ScheduledCommand(){
FlowPanel flowpanel;
            ..
flowpanel = new FlowPanel();
flowpanelReport.add(new HTML("<menu><b>My Firts Chart</b></menu>"));

ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() { 
                ..
LineChart lineChart = new LineChart();
Datatable ..
lineChart.draw(dataTable);
panelChart.add(lineChart);
addPanel(panelChart);
}
private void addPanel(LayoutPanel panelChart) {
flowpanel.add(panelChart);
}
flowpanelReport.add(new HTML("<menu><b>My Second Chart</b></menu>"));
}
}
```

I'd like to see widgets in this order:My First Chart (HTML);Chart;My Second Chart (HTML);

But they are processed in this order:My First Chart (HTML);My Second Chart (HTML);Chart;

The Chart is always the last, any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is always the last one, because it takes time to load the chart library and only after that's done, you add the panel.

You can change your code to look something like this:

```
final FlowPanel chartPanel = new FlowPanel();
flowpanel.add(chartPanel);

chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        chartPanel.add(**YOUR CHART HERE**);
    }
});

flowpanel.add(**SOME OTHER CONTENT**);
```

That way, you create a placeholder (`chartPanel`) that is inserted in order and is filled when the chart library finished loading. `**SOME OTHER CONTENT**` will appear below the chart.

Comment: Thanks but I can't to define in this context a final object, but if I define a property as 'code'private FlowPanel flowpanel;'code' and then the rest of code as your hint, the chart is always the last one.

Comment: @django Updated my answer. And why exactly can't you use `final` variables?

Comment: Because I need to write <code>flowPanel = new FlowPanel()</code> for four times. But I tried to set 'final' changing my code and the situation has not changed.

Comment: Furthermore 'flowpanel.add(chartPanel);' before 'new Runnable()' doesn't works because the chartPanel is not initialized.

Comment: OMG! I'm so tired, sorry! It works!! Thanks a lot @Baz.